# Unable to build iOS project using command line but fine via Xcode interface

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit, xcodebuild

I have an Xcode project. When in Xcode interactively, I am able to run/build/archive using the Ad_Hoc_Distribution configuration but when I run:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -configuration Ad_Hoc_Distribution clean build
```

inside my project, I get an error:

```
/Users/esg/Documents/app-ios/testapp/testapp/AppDelegate.h:14:9: fatal error: 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
    ^
1 error generated.
```

What would cause this to fail from the command line when it works via the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team has encountered this same issue. After upgrading from Xcode 4.3.2 to 4.4.1, files that used to be found correctly no longer do.

By comparing the output of xcodebuild vs. Xcode's own build logs, and then comparing vs. our Xcode 4.3.2 build logs, we discovered that xcodebuild and Xcode IDE do not build with the same header dependencies anymore. When xcodebuild runs a 4.4.1 build, it uses an incorrect base directory for include files, which does not include the entire current path leading to the .xcodeproj directory. The last two directory nodes in the folder path appear to be truncated.

But building from Xcode IDE worked fine.

We worked around this problem by adding the correct header paths, as Xcode reports it, as an additional header dependency:

[image: corporate info redacted to protect, well, me]

$(SRCROOT) is what seems to be interpreted incorrectly when xcodebuild is employed. It should contain the two subdirectories I inserted in the second line.

I can only conclude that there is a ripe and spicy new bug in the xcode/xcodebuild interaction, but you can fix your header dependencies to at least get things compiling.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is very similar to the way that I solved it - basically I edited the pbxproj file manually, adding the required header search paths whenever I found the other paths that should be included. It works now.

Comment: We determined that this was due to the use of a SRCROOT= directive on our xcodebuild command line. We took it out and our builds stopped failing. Why they were working with Xcode 4.3.2 is unknown. The value for SRCROOT= appeared to be correct, but we just worked around the problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

See my own issue regarding this.

[xcodebuild header files not found in ReskIt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943956/xcodebuild-header-files-not-found-in-reskit)

I resolved it by changing nothing, but by adding a workspace and a scheme and used it to build. All the header settings were the same as it is being set for Xcode GUI to build.