# xcodebuild header files not found in ReskIt

Tags: xcode, restkit, xcodebuild

I am pretty new to Xcode development. We are using command line tools to build the iOS project. We kep on getting the RestKit/RestKit.h file not found error while using command line build. If we use the normal XCode utility build it build without any issues.. There are few more thrid party code being used which may also have the same issue.

The folder struture of the project is like this.

```
--Project.xcodeproject
-- RestKit
   ----RestKit.xcodeproject
--SDWebImageKit
  -----SDWebImageKit.xcodeproject
  -----SDWebImage
        ---- .h and .m files
```

What path should we set in header search paths to properly build this in xcodebuild command line utility.

Comment: Does it always happen? How are you calling `xcodebuild`? Is it specific to debug or release builds?

Comment: I added $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../Headers in header search path and the RestKit error is not showing. Error now is sdwebimage/uiimageview+webcache.h file not found

XCode GUI build works without any issues

Comment: I resolved all the issues by creating a workspace, adding a scheme and building hte workspace using xcodebuild. I didnt have to chnage any of the header settings as being set in XCode GUI. Thanks for your help...Wain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved all the issues by creating a workspace, adding a scheme and building hte workspace using xcodebuild. I didnt have to chnage any of the header settings as being set in XCode GUI.